# hazelcast - is there a way to iterate over a map keys and/or values to query

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have an class that has a map as one of its fields. Is there a way in Hazelcast using predicates to query for object where the key in the map has the values I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

```java
MapProxyImpl cache = (MapProxyImpl)cacheName.getNativeCache();
Iterator<String> iterator = cache.keySet().iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String key = iterator.next();

    System.out.println(key);   
}
```

where cacheName is ur Cache Object given by spring.

Answer (score 0):

Queries on maps are not yet implemented (as they are out of the box for lists / arrays). It is, however, possible to implement your own `ValueExtractor` to extract the values from the map based on your key.

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/manual/html-single/index.html#custom-attributes